# Remove unused jar from eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

How can I remove unused jars from my project in Eclipse? I have about 30 jars in my system, but I'm only using some jars. Any suggestions?

Comment: if you use maven it will be easy to detect an used jars

Comment: http://classpathhelper.sourceforge.net/ try this it will help you to get rid of unused JAR.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the project,in the list click on Build path --> Configure build path --> in that popup select Libraries.select the jars which are not required and click Remove button.